# Does Storm Trident can only doing JOIN within batches?

Tags: cluster-computing, distributed, apache-storm

I want to implement a JOIN semantics, and I try the join method in Trident topology.
I find that join is doing between batches.
If the join between two stream with millions of tuples, does it must within one batches?

In the genderSpout, each batch has 3 tuples, so the Spout will emit 2 batchs
the ageSpout, each batch has 5 tuples, so the Spout will emit only 1 batch

And I do a LEFT OUTER JOIN with the JoinType

The output of the test-code is:

```
1 man 15
2 woman 18
1 man 19
3 woman NULL
4 man NULL
1 woman NULL
```

From the output, I find that the first four result is joining between the first batch from genderSpout and the first batch from ageSpout.
And the last two result is the joining between the second batch from genderSpout with the empty batch from ageSpout.
So the result is not correct for the JOIN semantics, since my desired result of genderSpout LEFT JOIN ageSpout is:

```
1 man 15
1 man 19
2 woman 18
3 woman NULL
4 man 20
1 woman 15
1 woman 19
```

So my question is: if there are millions of tuples in the both side(Spout) of JOIN, should I put them in one batch to get the correct result?

Or the way I go though is wrong, would you please tell me how should I do to get the correct result for OUTER JOIN semantics?

The test code as follow:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    Fields genderField = new Field("id", "gender");
    FixedBatchSpout genderSpout = new FixedBatchSpout(genderField, 3,
        new Values("1", "man"),
        new Values("2", "woman"),
        new Values("3", "woman"),
        new Values("4", "man"),
        new Values("1", "woman"));
    genderSpout.setCycle(false);

    Fields ageField = new Field("id2", "age");
    FiexedBatchSpout ageSpout = new FixedBatchSpout(new Fields("id2", "age"), 5,
        new Values("1", "15"),
        new Values("4", "20"),
        new Values("2", "18"),
        new Values("1", "19"));
    ageSpout.setCycle(false);

    List<Stream> allStreams = new ArrayList<Stream>();
    List<Fields> allFields = new ArrayList<Fields>();
    List<Fields> joinFileds = new ArrayList<Fields>();
    List<JoinType> joinTypes = new ArrayList<JoinType>();    

    TridentTopology topology = new TridentTopology();

    Stream genderStream = topology.newStream("genderIn", genderSpout);
    Stream ageStream = topology.newStream("ageIn", ageSpout);

    allStreams.add(genderStream);
    allStreams.add(ageStream);

    allFields.add(genderFields);
    allFields.add(ageFields);

    joinFields.add(new Field("id")));
    joinFields.add(new Field("id2"));

    joinTypes.add(JoinType.INNER);
    joinTypes.add(JoinType.OUTER);

    topology.join(allStreams, joinFields, new Filds("id", "gender", "age"), joinTypes)

    LocalCluster cluster = new LocalCluster();

    Config config = new Config()
    config.setDebug(false);
    config.setMaxSpoutPending(3);

    cluster.submitTopology("trident-join-test", config, topology.build());

    Thread.sleep(3000);
    cluster.shutdown();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have asked the same question in the https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!forum/storm-user:
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/storm-user/7fxAVgF2_0M

The answer from Jason Jackson is：
TridentTopology.join doesn't join across batches. You can use stateQuery and one of the partitionPersist to do streaming join  across batches.

Hope useful